# Parse time from string in UTC format in a way comparable with the current time stamp

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, timezone, utc

I would like to do create a pandas date range ranging from a parsed time to the current time, both in **UTC**. This is my best effort so far:

```
import dateutil
from datetime import datetime, timezone

start_time = dateutil.parser.isoparse ('2021-01-01T00Z')
end_time = datetime.now (timezone.utc)
```

Both timestamps are in the UTC timezone now, but creating the date range fails nevertheless:

```
> timestamps = pd.date_range (start=start_time, end=end_time, freq='H')
TypeError: Start and end cannot both be tz-aware with different timezones
```

Cause is that the tzinfo objects of both timestaps are UTC like, but of different types:

```
> print (start_time, end_time, type (start_time.tzinfo), type (end_time.tzinfo))
datetime.datetime(2020, 1, 1, 0, 0, tzinfo=tzutc()),
datetime.datetime(2021, 5, 13, 5, 45, 56, 866181, tzinfo=datetime.timezone.utc),
dateutil.tz.tz.tzutc,
datetime.timezone
```

So I'm stuck here. Is there a valid way to do this ? This could be either by parsing an ISO time format in UTC via 'datetime' or getting the current system time in UTC via dateutil. I did not find a solution for any of these.

Edit: Copy/paste error in the code examples

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not a pro but I made some research and found this solution using [`astimezone()`](https://www.kite.com/python/docs/datetime.datetime.astimezone):

```
import dateutil
from datetime import datetime, timezone

start_time = dateutil.parser.isoparse ('2021-01-01T00Z').astimezone(timezone.utc)
end_time = datetime.now (timezone.utc)
timestamps = pd.date_range (start=start_time, end=end_time, freq='H')
timestamps
```

which gives :

```
DatetimeIndex(['2021-01-01 00:00:00+00:00', '2021-01-01 01:00:00+00:00',
               '2021-01-01 02:00:00+00:00', '2021-01-01 03:00:00+00:00',
               '2021-01-01 04:00:00+00:00', '2021-01-01 05:00:00+00:00',
               '2021-01-01 06:00:00+00:00', '2021-01-01 07:00:00+00:00',
               '2021-01-01 08:00:00+00:00', '2021-01-01 09:00:00+00:00',
               ...
               '2021-05-12 21:00:00+00:00', '2021-05-12 22:00:00+00:00',
               '2021-05-12 23:00:00+00:00', '2021-05-13 00:00:00+00:00',
               '2021-05-13 01:00:00+00:00', '2021-05-13 02:00:00+00:00',
               '2021-05-13 03:00:00+00:00', '2021-05-13 04:00:00+00:00',
               '2021-05-13 05:00:00+00:00', '2021-05-13 06:00:00+00:00'],
              dtype='datetime64[ns, UTC]', length=3175, freq='H')
```

Comment: '2021-01-01T00Z' should be parsed to UTC directly due to the `Z`, no? Why is astimezone needed?

Comment: Like I said, I'm not a pro but it seems like it's parsed to another `UTC` class(`dateutil.tz.tz.tzutc`) so I added `astimezone()` to convert it to the same class(`<class 'pytz.UTC'>`).

Comment: For UTC it should not make a difference it the timezone object comes from dateutil, zoneinfo, pytz etc. Give it a try (for other time zones, it does matter though; especially whatch out for pytz).

Comment: Hmm, this does not work here (my timezone/local configuration), because the 'astimezone ()' function does not only set the timezone member, but converts the given parsed time from local time into that timezone. So I do get:

> start_time=dateutil.parser.isoparse ('2020-01-01').astimezone (timezone.utc)
> end_time = datetime.now (timezone.utc)
> print (pd.date_range (start=start_time, end=end_time, freq='D'))

DatetimeIndex(['2019-12-31 23:00:00+00:00', '2020-01-01 23:00:00+00:00',
               '2020-01-02 23:00:00+00:00', '2020-01-03 23:00:00+00:00',
...

Answer (score 1):

Ok, with that hint of zazz in the comment above, I got it !

```
start_time = dateutil.parser.isoparse ('2020-01-01T00Z').astimezone (timezone.utc)
end_time = datetime.now (timezone.utc)

pd.date_range (start=start_time, end=end_time, freq='D')
```

The secret ingredient here is the 'Z' modifier in the parsed string which tags it to be in UTC time. Then, 'astimezone (timezone.utc)' does only change the timezone tag, but does not convert the timestamp value. Works !

Thank you very much for your help !

Comment: You're welcome, I did it right at the beginning then I edited my post ! If my answer helped, I'll be grateful if you accept my answer.